# Using Microsoft Software and license keys

Tags: windows, license

Do software packages from Microsoft like Windows 7, Office 2010, Visio etc. have any link to the context in which they originally have been obtained (e.g. obtained via MSDNAA or BizSpark in particular) ?

**Can Microsoft software and Microsoft license keys considered to be separate things and the use of a software is legal as long the used license key is legal (regardless where the software came from) ?**

Can I use for example say a copy of Windows 7 I obtained via the Microsoft BizSpark program (as used at work) and use it with another (private) Windows 7 key ? Supposing the key is a legal one of course would that be a legal use of the BizSpark software or does the software itself (without taking any license key into account) has any link to the BizSpark account it is coming from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Microsoft products exist in different variations in terms of the installation packages (binaries). For example, volume license binaries are different from the MSDN and retail binaries. This is because of different activation methods used. In general, when a binary distribution is not compatible with a given product key, the product installation won't accept that product key at all. This happens, for example, for MVL (volume license) binaries in combination with MSDN product keys. As to my knowledge there's difference in BizSpark binaries when compared to MSDN binaries. However, BizSpark product keys are different from MSDN product keys (even those BizSpark-issued MSDN subscriptions).

*In any case, to get a really authoritative answer I think you'd have to analyse the respective EULAs for the product you are concerned, and/or get an official statement from Microsoft.*

Comment: Your answer was a big help for me, thank you.